# Inputs to eager execution function cannot be Keras symbolic tensors, but found

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to obtain the jacobian of my model wrt an input (sample_x which is a binary vector in numpy).

```
print("Initiating gradient checker")
    sample_x_tensor = sample_x.toarray()
    sample_x_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(sample_x.toarray())
    sample_x_tensor = tf.cast(sample_x_tensor, tf.float32)

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(sample_x_tensor)
        y_pred = model(sample_x_tensor)
        print(y_pred[0])

    jacobian = tape.jacobian(y_pred, sample_x_tensor)
```

Model is a straightforward Keras binary classification model, Keras 2.15 and Tensorflow 2. Getting the following exception:

```
tensorflow.python.eager.core._SymbolicException: Inputs to eager execution function cannot be Keras symbolic tensors, but found [<tf.Tensor 'Reshape:0' 
shape=(1,) dtype=float32>]
```

To my understanding, TF2 has eager execution by default. Any idea how I can rectify this?

Comment: shouldn't you call `model.predict(sample_x_tensor)` rather than `model(sample_x_tensor)?`

Comment: Interesting, the reason I do this is because GradientTape only takes a Tensor argument. Therefore, I convert my numpy array to a tensor and then supply it as an argument to the model as per here: https://keras.io/models/model/ where you can suppply the tensor as an argument to the model. Since I am "watching" this tensor for its behaviour, is this not the correct way to do it?

Comment: The link you provided is for creating a keras model, but when a model is created, you can only call the predict function on it

Comment: When doing your suggestion, I get: "ValueError: If your data is in the form of symbolic tensors, you should specify the `steps` argument (instead of the `batch_size` argument, because symbolic tensors are expected to produce batches of input data)." Should it work out of the box - that I can call predict on the tensor?

Comment: I am not sure about the error, sorry, but a keras model should work if you call the predict function and give it a batch of inputs.

Comment: Not when using gradient tape it seems like this

Answer (score 0):

Using the **Code Snippet** you provided and adding **basic Keras Binary Classification** Model.

Code used for reproduction:

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x  # Using Google Colab

import tensorflow as tf  # Tensorflow 2.2.0-rc3
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_shape = (2,)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

print("Initiating gradient checker")
sample_x_tensor = tf.random.normal((100,2))
# sample_x_tensor = sample_x.toarray()
# sample_x_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(sample_x.toarray())
sample_x_tensor = tf.cast(sample_x_tensor, tf.float32)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(sample_x_tensor)
    y_pred = model(sample_x_tensor)
    print(y_pred[0])

jacobian = tape.jacobian(y_pred, sample_x_tensor)
```

This returns:

```
Initiating gradient checker
tf.Tensor([0.38266268], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
```

It executed successfully, but I would suggest a few things for you:

1. Check your Model **Layers** and see if it is processing the **right data types**.
2. Check your **Input Data Shapes** and **Type**, make sure that it is compatible with the layers used. (Tensor Datatype as much as possible)

Hope this helps you.